# selenium webdriver too slow load page on firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

I am running Selenium Webdriver 2.40.0 with Java on 64-bit windows and Firefox 27.0.1.
i have getting issues to loading page too slow on Firefox.
i have deployed web application on local machine and other virtual machine also.
Scripts are running well on Internet Explorer 11,
before update Firefox 23.0 Scripts are running well on Firefox 21.0,
but after update page loading get too slow.
on Selenium RC script running fine on Firefox but problem coming on Webdriver..
other URL are also working fine on webdrirver with firefox,problem getting to only deployed java web application on my network machine.

here is my code

```
 FirefoxProfile ff = new FirefoxProfile();<br>

 FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla       Firefox\\firefox.exe"));

 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary,ff);<br>

 driver.get(URL);
```

Comment: I'm afraid we can't really help you without additional information. What exactly is "too slow"? Does the Firefox executable take too long to actually open the FF window? Or does the window get opened OK, but then the actual page load is slow? What is happening while you wait? CPU/HDD load, FF window freeze, Java code after `driver.get()` running etc.? Do other pages work ok? Try to pinpoint the problem - make your web application smaller and smaller, remove things that could conflict with WebDriver somehow and see if it gets better after some time or if it is an issue even with a Hello world.

Comment: @Slanec: For me the Firefox window will open but the page won't load for a long long time. If I open the same URL in my Firefox profile it loads way faster.

Answer (score 0):

A possible cause is security software (firewall,anti-virus) that blocks or 
restricts Firefox or the plugin-container process without informing you, 
possibly after detecting changes (update) to the Firefox program.

Remove all rules for Firefox and the plugin-container from the 
permissions list in the firewall and let your firewall ask again for
permission to get full unrestricted access to internet for 
Firefox and the plugin-container process and the updater process.

See:

https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Server+not+found

https://support.mozilla.org/kb/Firewalls